# Password protect wordpress on Bitnami

Tags: wordpress, virtual-machine, google-cloud-platform, bitnami, .htpasswd

I'm new to Bitnami and currently using a Google Cloud Platform for my VMs.
I'm trying to password protect a wordpress installation for 1 of my VMs. It's a dev site so only going to be using the IP address to access the site.

However following the instructions I found [here](https://wiki.bitnami.com/Components/Apache#How_to_create_a_password_to_protect_access_to_apache.3f), I am unable to write in the opt/bitnami/apache2/ folder. Everytime I try to run the commands in the above linked instruction, I get the following error 
**/opt/bitnami/apache2/bin/htpasswd.bin: cannot create file opt/bitnami/apache2/wordpress_users**

I've tried to manually change the permissions on the folder and it doesn't work. I can't seem to run any commands with SU because there is no password provided for shell access (using only a ssh cert file)

Can anyone can offer help as to what I'm doing wrong or what I'm missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the idea but it didn't work, I tried with sudo having my apache2/ folder set to 755 and ownership back to it's original setting.

On the other hand.... I manage to solve my problem. Seems that in the original on how to call your command there is a part missing! Well it's missing for me cause by adding the fullpath to the original file I was able to successfully get a password in place and things are now working perfectly

```
$ opt/bitnami/apache2/bin/htpasswd -cb apache2/wordpress_users username password
```

Took me too long to get that working... Thanks for the help, without you I wouldn't have made a typo that made me rethink the error! Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami developer here,

It is not necessary to modify permission for the `apache2` folder nor the `htpasswd.bin` file. The `bitnami` user does not have a password by default but is allowed to run commands with higher privileges using `sudo`. Could you please try to revert the permission changes and run the command with `sudo`?

```
cd /opt/bitnami
sudo apache2/bin/htpasswd -cb apache2/wordpress_users your_desired_username your_desired_password
```

Let me know if you have any other issue or if it worked for you.

Best regards,

Gonzalo

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami developer here,

Sorry I didn't mentioned that you need to change to the `/opt/bitnami` directory first as I thought you already did it. Also, you have to run command with sudo because `root` is the owner of the apache2 folder.

Apart from that, I'm glad you could fix your issue!

Best regards,
Gonzalo

Comment: I was in the /opt/bitnami directory and still had to type in the full command "opt/bitnami/apache2/bin/htpasswd" in order to get it working...